# How to use Bigquery JSON functions in Google Cloud Datalab

Tags: json, ipython, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab

I am calling Bigquery within Google Cloud Datalab notebooks and I want to use the [JSON functions that can be used in BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#jsonfunctions). However it turns out, because JSON functions use "$" as a reference to the segment within string, while Cloud Datalab uses "$" to refer to global variables; they conflict and give errors.

Example (not reproducible as I couldn't find any JSON-like strings in samples)

```
%%sql --module events_query
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(eventTypeParams, '$.restaurant-name") as str
FROM [foodit-prod:analytics.analytics_event]
```

When I run the thing:

```
events_run = bq.Query(events_query)
events = events_run.to_dataframe()
```

This is the error I receive:

> ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>   ----> 1 events_run = bq.Query(events_query)
>         2 events = events_run.to_dataframe()
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/bigquery/_query.pyc in
>   **init**(self, sql, context, values, udfs, data_sources, **kwargs)
>        90       values = kwargs
>        91 
>   ---> 92     self._sql = gcp.data.SqlModule.expand(sql, values, udfs)
>        93 
>        94     # We need to take care not to include the same UDF code twice so we use sets.
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/data/_sql_module.pyc in
>   expand(sql, args, udfs)
>       127     """
>       128     sql, args = SqlModule.get_sql_statement_with_environment(sql, args)
>   --> 129     return _sql_statement.SqlStatement.format(sql._sql, args, udfs)
>       130 
>       131
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/data/_sql_statement.pyc in
>   format(sql, args, udfs)
>       137     code = []
>       138     SqlStatement._find_recursive_dependencies(sql, args, code=code,
>   --> 139                                               resolved_vars=resolved_vars)
>       140 
>       141     # Rebuild the SQL string, substituting just '$' for escaped $ occurrences,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/data/_sql_statement.pyc in
>   _find_recursive_dependencies(sql, values, code, resolved_vars, resolving_vars)
>        80 
>        81     # Get the set of $var references in this SQL.
>   ---> 82     dependencies = SqlStatement._get_dependencies(sql)
>        83     for dependency in dependencies:
>        84       # Now we check each dependency. If it is in complete - i.e., we have an expansion
>
> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gcp/data/_sql_statement.pyc in
>   _get_dependencies(sql)
>       202           dependencies.append(variable)
>       203       elif dollar:
>   --> 204         raise Exception('Invalid sql; $ with no following $ or identifier: %s.' % sql)
>       205     return dependencies
>       206
>
> Exception: Invalid sql; $ with no following $ or identifier: SELECT
>   JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(eventTypeParams, "'\$'.restaurant-name") as str
>   FROM [foodit-prod:analytics.analytics_event].

I tried putting the $ sign in different quotes or escaping etc. None worked. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
%%sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(
    "{'book': { 
        'category':'fiction', 
        'title':'Harry Potter'}}", 
    "$$.book.category");
```

or from your example,

```
%%sql --module events_query
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(eventTypeParams, '$$.restaurant-name') as str
FROM [foodit-prod:analytics.analytics_event]
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much!

It still sucks though because you can't just copy-paste your code from BigQuery or from a file as they are. You have to add that extra $ sign. I tried to use in BQ with the double $$ but that didn't work there. So we'll have different syntaxes for the same company's products, it's a bit weird :)

Comment: I encountered a similar issue when using UDF in Google Datalab. Please mark this answer as accepted if it has solved your issue

Comment: As a workaround to keep queries the same between BQ and Datalab, you could create your own gcp.bigquery wrapper function which automatically adds the extra `$` in a SQL string